# Delete web-based OneNote notebook

Tags: onedrive, onenote

I have a web-based OneNote notebook in my skydrive. So in the skydrive folder I only see a link to the notebook. I think that if I delete the link, then the notebook will be still out there, but I just won't have the link. So how do I delete the notebook itself? I can't find that delete button in either web or windows OneNote applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow these directions you can delete a notebook. Be sure that you log into the OneDrive WEBSITE, very important.

Delete or restore files and folders
You can delete specific files on OneDrive, or you can delete entire folders and all the files in them.

Delete files and folders

From the OneDrive website
Go to the OneDrive website.

You might need to sign in with your Microsoft account.

Pick the items you want to delete by selecting the check box in the upper-right corner of items.

On the bar at the top of the page, tap or click Manage, choose Delete, and then tap or click Delete.

Note

If you delete items that are shared with you, they're moved to the owner's recycle bin. If you delete items from a group, they're permanently deleted.

In Windows 8.1, Windows RT 8.1, or using the OneDrive desktop app
Restore deleted items

From the OneDrive website
In Windows 8.1, Windows RT 8.1, or using the OneDrive desktop app
Note

Answer (score 0):

To delete part of the notebook: browse the Notebok you will see the Tabs and Pages of the notebook on the right. Select a tab or a page and right click over the label, you should see an option labeled `X Delete`. Selecting this prompt to confirm deletion.

To delete the whole notebook. Select in SkyDrive and right click. In the pop-up menu select Delete. This will be removed but you can Undo it. To permanently delete empty the Recycle bin in the lower left.

Comment: Wouldn't the delete button on skydrive produce the same result as if I would delete it on my PC and then sync?